# Unity Asset Store Tools Problem

Tags: unity, asset-management

So I downloaded Asset Store Tools in the Unity Asset Store. When I upload my asset to my package, I get this popup:

> **Wrong project path** *The path selected must be inside the currently active project. Note that the AssetStoreTools folder is removed
>   automatically before the package enters the asset store.*

My Unity is version **5.4.0b25**. I've tried other assets and reinstalled Unity, I still get the same popup.

Screenshot:
[image: Popup]

Comment: So, what's the project path? What's the asset path?

Comment: @Byte56 the asset folder i'm gonna post to the Asset Store.

Comment: What are the literal paths... Is the asset inside the project path?

Comment: @Byte56 The asset is inside a a folder in the project path. [Folder image](https://s31.postimg.org/63z16r64r/Screen_Shot_2016_07_12_at_3_46_02_PM.png) i just click the ModUI folder then click open then the popup shows

Comment: I'm guessing the Asset Store Tools folder needs to be inside your ModUI folder.

Comment: @Byte56 Just tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Were you able to find the issue? I have the same one.

Comment: @xtrimsky, could you confirm that your problem *really is* exactly as it is listed, here? I have looked up the error code, and found it on both Unity Answers and the Unity forums, but all instances are encountered specifically when *uploading* assets to the asset store

Comment: @Gnemlock Yes this is when I want to upload assets. My assets are ready, both on local and I have the package ready online. But I cannot upload the assets.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been posted several times on the Unity forums, and while I should think one would run into it before posting on here, I will repost it just in case.

[This one answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1078000/how-to-include-project-settings-when-submitting-fo.html) popped up across all iterations I could find, most commonly marked as the most useful answer.

> To quote:
>
> Hi :),
>
> just an adjucated guess<sup>*[sic]*</sup>: setting the category of your product to Complete Projects in the AssetStoreManager seems to do the trick.

---

The only user that did not find it useful later put it down to the fact that they were using an older version for the assets, and a *beta* version of Unity. If the above does not work, it would be a good idea to ensure you are uploading with the most recent *stable* release of the software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's the first time I saw this answer. But sadly it didn't help. I have the latest stable unity (5.4.1), the project is on the same version, the category is set to Complete Projects. But it just doesn't work, does the same exact error :(.